# in mobile browsers, the footer image does not repeat, but the background image does and is fine

Tags: html, css

I have webpage that works fine on the desktop browsers, but when I open it on iPhone, the back-ground image repeats but not the footer image. They have almost same css code, what can be the issue?

here is my css code for the body

```
body.login {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:relative; 
   background: #161616 url(../img/login-page-bg_01.png) left top repeat-x;
   font-family: roboto,"Helvetica Neue",helvetica,arial,sans-serif; 
   font-size:12px;
   line-height: 1.7em;
   height:750px;}
```

and here is the css code for the footer

```
.login div.footer{
margin:0;
padding:0;
background:url(../img/login-page-bg-footer.png) left top repeat-x; 
position:relative;
bottom:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height: 117px;
z-index:5;
    }
```

the problem is the body bg image repeats but the footer image just repeat once.

Comment: `repeat-x` means repeat horizontally and not vertically. You don't want it to repeat?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be repeated horizontally.Both bg and footer image are tiny column of image to be repeated in x axis to make the complete width image.

Comment: Please format your CSS more readable.

Comment: Sure, I`ve done already. Thanks

Comment: You can use the code inspector to debug on your iPhone, if you have a mac, as it requires safari 6. Have a look at this to find out how: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari/

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing all your code, these could be issues:

- Mobile Safari doesn't render VERY large (dimension, not filesize) images very well.
- `width: 100%` only means something if its parent has a set width.
- Try removing the `position`, `left` and `bottom`. They're useless in this case.

To see if the element itself is big enough, you can add a background color:

```
background: red url(../img/login-page-bg-footer.png) left top repeat-x;
```

I like 'red' for that. Is the red big or small?